# Kubernetes job keeps spinning up pods which end up with the 'Error' status

Tags: kubernetes

I'm working on a Kubernetes cron job which represents an integration test; it is Go test binary that is compiled with `go test -c` and copied into a Docker container run by the cron job. The Kubernetes YAML is starts similar to the following:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
spec:
  schedule: "*/15 * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 7
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 7
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          restartPolicy: Never
```

At some point, the integration test starting failing (exiting with code 1). I can see that the job has the same duration as its age:

```
$ kubectl get jobs -l app=integration-test
NAME                          COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
integration-test-1592457300   0/1           7m20s      7m20s
```

The `kubectl get pods` commands shows that pods being created more frequently than every 15 minutes as I would expect from the cron schedule:

```
$ kubectl get pods -l app=integration-test
NAME                                READY   STATUS   RESTARTS   AGE
integration-test-1592457300-224x8   0/1     Error    0          92s
integration-test-1592457300-5f8sz   0/1     Error    0          7m33s
integration-test-1592457300-9zvjq   0/1     Error    0          3m57s
integration-test-1592457300-th7sf   0/1     Error    0          6m26s
integration-test-1592457300-vhbr2   0/1     Error    0          5m17s
```

This behavior of spinning up new pods is problematic because it contributes to the running pod count on the node - essentially, it consumes resources.

How can I make it such that the cron job doesn't keep spinning up new pods, but only does one every 15 minutes, and doesn't continue to consume resources if the job fails?

#### Update

A simplified example of this uses a Kubernetes YAML adapted from https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/:

```
$ cat cronjob.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster; exit 1
          restartPolicy: Never
```

Note that it exits with code 1. If I run this using `kubernetes apply -f cronjob.yaml` and then check the pods, I see

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                                    READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
hello-1592459760-fnvcw                                  0/1     Error       0          30s
hello-1592459760-w75lt                                  0/1     Error       0          31s
hello-1592459760-xzhwn                                  0/1     Error       0          20s
```

The ages of the pods are less than a minute apart; in other words, pods are spun up before the cron interval has elapsed. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's quite specific scenario and it's hard to guess what you want to achievie and if it will work for you.

[concurrencyPolicy: Forbid](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#concurrency-policy) prevents to create another `job` if previous was not `completed`. But I think that is not the case here.

[restartPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy) applies to `pod` (however in `Job template` you can use only `OnFailure` and `Never`). If you will set `restartPolicy` to `Never`, `job` will create automatically new `pods` till completion.

> A Job creates one or more Pods and ensures that a specified number of them successfully terminate. As pods successfully complete, the Job tracks the successful completions.

If you set `restartPolicy: Never` it will be creating pods till it will reach [backoffLimit](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#pod-backoff-failure-policy), however those `pods` will be still visible in your cluster with `Error` status as each pod exit with `status 1`. You would need to remove it manually.
If you would set `restartPolicy: OnFailure` it will be restarting one `pod` and will not create more.

But there is another way. What is considered as `completed` job?

**Examples:**

**1. `restartPolicy: OnFailure`**

```
$ kubectl get po,jobs,cronjob
NAME                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/hello-1592495280-w27mt   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          5m21s
pod/hello-1592495340-tzc64   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          4m21s
pod/hello-1592495400-w8cm6   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          3m21s
pod/hello-1592495460-jjlx5   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   4          2m21s
pod/hello-1592495520-c59tm   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   3          80s
pod/hello-1592495580-rrdzw   0/1     Error              2          20s
NAME                         COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/hello-1592495220   0/1           6m22s      6m22s
job.batch/hello-1592495280   0/1           5m22s      5m22s
job.batch/hello-1592495340   0/1           4m22s      4m22s
job.batch/hello-1592495400   0/1           3m22s      3m22s
job.batch/hello-1592495460   0/1           2m22s      2m22s
job.batch/hello-1592495520   0/1           81s        81s
job.batch/hello-1592495580   0/1           21s        21s
NAME                  SCHEDULE      SUSPEND   ACTIVE   LAST SCHEDULE   AGE
cronjob.batch/hello   */1 * * * *   False     6        25s             15m
```

Each `job` will create only 1 `pod` which will be restarted till `job` will be `finished` or will be considered as `completed` by `CronJob`.

If you will describe `CronJob` in `Event` section you can find.

```
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age                  From                Message
  ----    ------            ----                 ----                -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  18m                  cronjob-controller  Created job hello-1592494740
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  17m                  cronjob-controller  Created job hello-1592494800
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  16m                  cronjob-controller  Created job hello-1592494860
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  15m                  cronjob-controller  Created job hello-1592494920
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  14m                  cronjob-controller  Created job hello-1592494980
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  13m                  cronjob-controller  Created job hello-1592495040
  Normal  SawCompletedJob   12m                  cronjob-controller  Saw completed job: hello-1592494740
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  12m                  cronjob-controller  Created job hello-1592495100
  Normal  SawCompletedJob   11m                  cronjob-controller  Saw completed job: hello-1592494800
  Normal  SuccessfulDelete  11m                  cronjob-controller  Deleted job hello-1592494740
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  11m                  cronjob-controller  Created job hello-1592495160
  Normal  SawCompletedJob   10m                  cronjob-controller  Saw completed job: hello-1592494860
```

Why job `hello-1592494740` was considered as `Completed`? `Cronjob` default value of `.spec.backoffLimit` is 6 (this information can be found in docs). If `job` will fail 6 times (pod will fail to restart 6 times) `Cronjob` will consider this `job` as `Completed` and it will remove it. As `job` was removed, also `pod` will be removed.

However, in your example, `pod` was created, pod executed date and echo command and then exit with code 1. Even if `pod` is Crashing it wrote information. As last command was `exit 1` so it will be Crashing till it reach limit. As per example below:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
hello-1592495400-w8cm6   0/1     Terminating        6          5m51s
hello-1592495460-jjlx5   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          4m51s
hello-1592495520-c59tm   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          3m50s
hello-1592495580-rrdzw   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   4          2m50s
hello-1592495640-nbq59   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   4          110s
hello-1592495700-p6pcx   0/1     Error              3          50s
user@cloudshell:~ (project)$ kubectl logs hello-1592495520-c59tm
Thu Jun 18 15:55:13 UTC 2020
Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
```

**2. `restartPolicy: Never` and `backoffLimit: 0`**

YAML below was used:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster; exit 1
          restartPolicy: Never
      backoffLimit: 0
```

**Output**

```
$ kubectl get po,jobs,cronjob
NAME                         READY   STATUS   RESTARTS   AGE
pod/hello-1592497320-svd6k   0/1     Error    0          44s
NAME                         COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/hello-1592497320   0/1           44s        44s
NAME                  SCHEDULE      SUSPEND   ACTIVE   LAST SCHEDULE   AGE
cronjob.batch/hello   */1 * * * *   False     0        51s             11m

$ kubectl describe cronjob
...
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age                  From                Message
  ----    ------            ----                 ----                -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  12m                  cronjob-controller  Created job hello-1592496720
  Normal  SawCompletedJob   11m                  cronjob-controller  Saw completed job: hello-1592496720
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  11m                  cronjob-controller  Created job hello-1592496780
  Normal  SawCompletedJob   10m                  cronjob-controller  Saw completed job: hello-1592496780
  Normal  SuccessfulDelete  10m                  cronjob-controller  Deleted job hello-1592496720
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  10m                  cronjob-controller  Created job hello-1592496840
  Normal  SuccessfulDelete  9m55s                cronjob-controller  Deleted job hello-1592496780
  Normal  SawCompletedJob   9m55s                cronjob-controller  Saw completed job: hello-1592496840
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  9m5s                 cronjob-controller  Created job hello-1592496900
  Normal  SawCompletedJob   8m55s                cronjob-controller  Saw completed job: hello-1592496900
  Normal  SuccessfulDelete  8m55s                cronjob-controller  Deleted job hello-1592496840
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  8m5s                 cronjob-controller  Created job hello-1592496960
  Normal  SawCompletedJob   7m55s                cronjob-controller  Saw completed job: hello-1592496960
  Normal  SuccessfulDelete  7m55s                cronjob-controller  Deleted job hello-1592496900
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  7m4s                 cronjob-controller  Created job hello-1592497020
```

This way only one `job` and one `pod` will be at the same time running (there might be 10 seconds gap when there will be 2 jobs and 2 pods).

```
$ kubectl get po,job
NAME                         READY   STATUS   RESTARTS   AGE
pod/hello-1592497440-twzlf   0/1     Error    0          70s
pod/hello-1592497500-2q7fq   0/1     Error    0          10s

NAME                         COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/hello-1592497440   0/1           70s        70s
job.batch/hello-1592497500   0/1           10s        10s
user@cloudshell:~ (project)$ kk get po,job
NAME                         READY   STATUS   RESTARTS   AGE
pod/hello-1592497500-2q7fq   0/1     Error    0          11s

NAME                         COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/hello-1592497500   0/1           11s        11s
```

I hope it cleared a bit. If you would like more precise answer, please give more information about your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Default [concurrencyPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#concurrency-policy): Allow.

You can set `concurrencyPolicy: Forbid` to avoid parallel running new jobs.

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  # Allow | Forbid | Replace
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
```